# I can not configure log4j2 properties file with multiple conditions

Tags: properties, conditional-statements, log4j2

I am an Elasticsearch user and I have to use a log4j2.properties file.
Unfortunately i can't get it to delete logs as I would like.

I want some log files (corresponding to a pattern) rotated  every day.
I also want the rotated log files to be deleted if it matches one of my 2 conditions:

- if they are more than  3 months old
- if the total size of these files exceeds 200 mega.

I try to use the PathCondition "ifany", described in this piece of log4j2 documentation:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

Here is my log4j2.properties file:

```
status = error

# log action execution errors for easier debugging
logger.action.name = org.elasticsearch.action
logger.action.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:es.logs}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.-10000m%n
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:es.logs}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = /var/log/elasticsearch
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = mylog-*.log
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.nestedConditions.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.nestedConditions.age = 90D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.nestedConditions.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.PathConditions.nestedConditions.exceeds = 200M
```

Currently, when I restart log4j2, I get the error message:

> main ERROR IfAccumulatedFileSize contains an invalid element or
>   attribute "age"

I would really appreciate any help on this subject. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Trying Changing your configuration for `DeleteAction` as per below -

```
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = /var/log/elasticsearch
appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = mylog-*.log
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.age = 90d
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 200MB
```

You can also refer to `log4j2` [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DeleteIfAccumulatedFileSize) for configuring multiple conditions. `Log4j2` documentation describes XML configuration. However, by referring to these examples, you can think and guess properties configuration also.

Comment: Thank you  @vikas, it works like a charm ! Would you kindly tell me if you know any good documentation about the syntax of .properties files for log4j2? I find the official documentation a bit disappointing ...

Comment: @ESCUREThomas Actually, there is almost no official documentation for properties file configuration of `log4j2`. It is just you have to understand XML configuration and then try converting it to properties configuration. I added documentation link in above answer also.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva Does this also delete existing files that were created before adding the DeleteAction? (It's not deleting the older files for me). Also, when does the deletion get triggered? Is that once every day? Or whenever the main file gets rolled over?

Comment: @NikhilOwalekar As per log4j documentation mentioned [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#Log_Archive_Retention_Policy:_Delete_on_Rollover) files are deleted at rollover time and it can delete any file, not just rolled over log file

Answer (score 0):

@Vikas answer did not work for me. I had to add .condition right before each ifAny.*. Something like:

```html
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.fileIndex = nomax
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*.json.gz
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifLastModified.age = 30D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 7GB
```

Please find an example here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/log4j2-properties-an-example-of-a-multiple-conditions-configuration-for-an-elasticsearch-7-cluster-7-6-1/249939.
Let me know if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

@gino thx for your very good example

following is a modification of original `log4j2.properties` and section `Server JSON` in Elasticsearch 7.9.1
It will remove files with extention `.gz` which modification date is longer than 14 days or if they cumulated size is bigger than 1GB (please replace configuration starting from `Delete` line)

Changes in count of logs files will be visible after 2 daily rotation of elasticsearch logs if you didn't change interval.

```
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basepath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.glob = ${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-*.gz
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.type = IfAny
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifLastModified.age = 14D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 1GB
```